# Camel adviceWith behaves differently when changing the order of weave statements

Tags: apache-camel

I have the following route for demo purposes

```
from("direct:external")
    .routeId("external")
    .to("http4://www.third-party.com/foo").id("ext");
```

For testing, I would like to
* replace the http4: endpoint with a direct: endpoint
* add a mock: endpoint at the end of the route for verification

I've added the following adviceWithRouteBuilder

```
context.getRouteDefinition("external").adviceWith(context, new AdviceWithRouteBuilder() {
    @Override
    public void configure() throws Exception {
        weaveAddLast().to("mock:result");
        weaveByToUri(".*http4://.*")
            .replace()
            .to("direct:foo");
    }
});
```

This one seems to work but if I change the order of the `weave*` statements, like so

```
public void configure() throws Exception {
    weaveByToUri(".*http4://.*")
        .replace()
        .to("direct:foo");
    weaveAddLast().to("mock:result");
}
```

It gives me the following error

> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: There are no outputs which matches: * in the route: Route(external)[[From[direct:external]] -> [pipeline -> [[To[direct:foo]]]]]

I would actually expect to get the same result, independent of the order.

Comment: For most of the usage I've had with Camel I've never used weaving functions for the functionality you'd like to achieve. What about using

`interceptSendToEndpoint(fromEndpoint).skipSendToOriginalEndpoint().to(toEndpoint);` ?

Since camel-test package is actually causing more pain than benefit I've created a camel-test-support package, which is a little bit easier to use. Please check it out, examples attached: https://github.com/gmaslowski/camel-test-support

Answer (score 10, accepted):

One thing to note here is that the `weave*` calls are only aware of the original RouteBuilder. So when you perform the `weaveByUri()` call first, it replaces `.to("http4://www.third-party.com/foo")` with `.to("direct:foo")`, which incidentally happens to be the last endpoint in your route. Now, when you perform the `weaveAddLast()` call, it looks for `"http4://www.third-party.com/foo"` but doesn't find it, since it was replaced by `"direct:foo"`. This results in an exception being thrown.

So if, hypothetically, there's another endpoint after the `"http4..."` endpoint such that it's not the last endpoint in your route anymore, your `adviceWith()` should work. For instance, it will work if your original route looked something like this:

```
from("direct://external")
  .routeId("external")
  .to("http4://www.third-party.com/foo")
  .id("ext")
  .to("direct://bar")
;
```

I should note that I think that this is a bug and that the order shouldn't matter.

Comment: Perfect answer, it's a pity that you didn't answer before the bounty timed out (that would have granted you 500 SO points).

Comment: Thanks I logged a ticket to see if we can improve/fix this: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CAMEL-10855